# Linq to Entities figure out count of rows without returning rows

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I hope one of you guys can help me with this question:
Given the method below, can I cause the count to be done on the DB Server rather than retrieve all the rows, and the function should not be running query for each search name, it should run exactly 1 SQL statement for each call of the function.[image]

Comment: It's usually a better idea to type in your code so others can copy it. To format text as code each line has to start with four spaces.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify your query dramatically by using `Contains` which will translated to a `WHERE IN` clause.  Then simply count the matching rows.

```
public static int CountEmployeesByName(IEnumerable<string> namesToSearch)
{
    using (var context = new ApplicationEntities())
    {
          return context.employees
                        .Where(e => namesToSearch.Contains(e.name))
                        .Count();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to say: can you do it with only 1 line of code change for the first part and one line of code change for the second part of the question?

Comment: I don't understand why there is a restriction.  This does both things - basically turns it into `select count(*) from employees where name in (....)`

Comment: That is the restriction I was given unfortunately.  I know how you feel, I wondered the same question.

Comment: I suppose you could use a PredicateBuilder from LinqKit but I don't see how you could do it in less than 3 line changes. At a minimum I think you'd need to change the definition of `queries`, the selection logic for each name, and the statement that sums the built up queries.